# Combining of logical conditions in IF statement

Tags: logical-operators

I just notice the if condition below:

```js
//1
if ((i >= 0) != (j >= 0))
 return false;
```

is just a short way for:

```js
//2
if((i>=0 && j < 0) || (i < 0 && j >=0))
 return false;
```

Going from 1. to 2. takes some time to figure out, but how do we deduce the logic to go from 2. to 1.?

Comment: Might as well make it just `return (i >= 0) == (j >= 0);` then, without any `if` :-)

Comment: I'm not sure this really needs the javascript tag (but the edit queue is full) - logic is the same irrespective of programming logic.

Comment: yeah, I removed the js tag (it just happened that I was doing js so I put in the tag)

Comment: I just wonder 1. way would actually not a good way to write code (as other people would need some more time to deduce *wtf is this...*) or even `return (i >= 0) == (j >= 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any two boolean statements A and B then `A != B` means that they are different. I.e. either A is true and B is false, or A is false and B is true. This goes also the other way if A is true and B is false, or A is false and B is true, then A does not equal B.

In other words `(A != B) = ((A && !B) || (!A && B))`. Therefore, statement 1 and 2 are the same

If you feel my argumentation is imprecise, you can use [truth tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) to proof it rigorous mathematically:

| A | B | A!=B | (A && !B) | (!A && B) | (A && !B) `||` (!A && B)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| true | true | **false** | false | false | **false** |
| true | false | **true** | true | false | **true** |
| false | true | **true** | false | true | **true** |
| false | false | **false** | false | false | **false** |

Answer (score 1):

If we call `(i >= 0)` something arbitrary like `A` and `(j >= 0)` something else like `B` then it stands to reason that `(i < 0)` is just `Not A` (often shown as `!A`) and `(j < 0)` would be `Not B` or `!B`

Meaning this block:

```
if((i>=0 && j < 0) || (i < 0 && j >=0))
 return false;
```

Can be represented as:

```
if ((A && !B) || (!A && B))
    return false;
else // you haven't specified this part but it's implied
    return true;
```

Now, if we approach this as:

> How do we get to the true value?

Then you realise it's the same as:

```
if ((A && B) || (!A && !B))
    return true;
else 
    return false;
```

Then we can call `(A && B)` something else like `C`; so it becomes:

```
if (C || !C)
    return true;
else 
    return false;
```

So, expanding out again, we can get:

```
if (A && B)
    return true;
else if (!(A && B)) 
    return true;
else 
    return false;
```

So, that's:

```
if ((i >= 0) && (j >= 0))
    return true;
else if (!( (i >= 0) && (j >= 0) ) )
    return true;
else 
    return false;
```

Which can evaluate to:

```
if (True && True)
    return true;
else if (False && False)
    return true;
else 
    return false;
```

Showing that it's as simple as:

```
if ( (i >= 0) == (j  >= 0) )
    return true;
else // if ( (i >= 0) != (j  >= 0) )
    return false;
```

So, we've gone around the houses but we've worked our way down from statement 2 to statement 1.

NOTE: Adam's answer is more concise and is accurate from a pure logic perspective; this is more to provide a broader overview as I know that some people learn better when they can see the process.